# React Native Element Type is Invalid. Check Render Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've looked around and most of these issues are a result if importing or exporting incorrectly but I've checked around my app and I'm not sure what I'm exporting/importing incorrectly. This is the exact error I'm getting.

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the
>   file it's defined in. Check the render method of `FooterTabs`.

Not sure what it means by render method. The component doesn't have a render method. Anyways...

So `FooterTabs` is just me rendering some footer tabs

```js
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import { Tabs, Tab, Icon } from 'react-native-elements'
import { HomeContainer, TrackLibraryContainer } from '~/containers'
import { NimbusCamera } from '~/components'

export default function FooterTabs (props) {
    console.log(props)
    FooterTabs.propTypes = {
        navigator: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        activeFooterTab: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        setFooterTab: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    }
    return (
        <Tabs>
            <Tab
                selected={props.activeFooterTab === "home"}
                titleStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 10}}
                selectedTitleStyle={{marginTop: -1, marginBottom: 6}}
                title="Home"
                onPress={(tab) => props.dispatch(props.setFooterTab("home"))}
                renderIcon={() => <Icon containerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 12}} color={'#5e6977'} type="ionicon" name='ios-home-outline' size={33} />}>
                <HomeContainer navigator={navigator}/>  
            </Tab>
            <Tab
                selected={props.activeFooterTab === "camera"}
                titleStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 10}}
                selectedTitleStyle={{marginTop: -1, marginBottom: 6}}
                title="Record Preview"
                onPress={(tab) => props.dispatch(props.setFooterTab("camera"))}
                renderIcon={() => <Icon containerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 12}} color={'#5e6977'} type="ionicon" name='ios-camera-outline' size={33} />}>
                <NimbusCamera navigator={navigator}/>   
            </Tab>
            <Tab
                titleStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 10}}
                selectedTitleStyle={{marginTop: -1, marginBottom: 6}}
                title="Available Streams"
                onPress={(tab) => props.dispatch(props.setFooterTab("library"))}
                renderIcon={() => <Icon containerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 12}} color={'#5e6977'} type="ionicon" name='ios-musical-notes-outline' size={33} />}>
                <TrackLibraryContainer navigator={navigator}/>  
            </Tab>
        </Tabs>
    )
}
```

I then export it in `app/components/index.js` like `export { default as FooterTabs } from './FooterTabs/FooterTabs'`

All other components that are imported are exported the same way.

I probably just need another set of eyes here. Let me know if you need to see any other files code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `navigator` is undefined, causing errors when rendering the child components. In this case, `navigator={navigator}` needs to be changed to `navigator={props.navigator}` in your `HomeContainer`, `NimbusCamera`, and `TrackerLibraryContainer` components.

Comment: Good catch there but I'm still getting the error :(

Comment: I would suggest trying to remove the `HomeContainer`, `NimbusCamera`, and `TrackerLibraryContainer` components one by one and see if it renders. If it renders after you remove one of the components, then it means that you should look at that component and see if something is wrong in there.

Comment: I wasn't exporting the Camera component. Whoops.

Comment: No worries. Note that this error can occur when there is a problem with the render of the a child components, so one of the steps that you would take to debug would be to remove the children one by one. In your case, you could remove the tabs one by one and see if it renders because the tabs seem to have the same/similar properties.